# Sentry.NLog not logging to Sentry

Tags: nlog, sentry

Trying to get Sentry wired up via NLog, and not having much luck.

Packages:

```xml
<package id="Sentry" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Sentry.NLog" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Both latest.

NLog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Debug"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.txt"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Sentry.NLog" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Sentry"
            name="sentry"
            dsn="https://secret"
            environment="test"
            includeEventProperties="True"
            layout="${message}"
            breadcrumbLayout="${message}"
            minimumBreadcrumbLevel="Debug"
            ignoreEventsWithNoException="False"
            includeEventDataOnBreadcrumbs="False"
            includeEventPropertiesAsTags="True"
            minimumEventLevel="Error" />    
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="sentry" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

Things I've checked:

- DSN. Copied and pasted from the Sentry portal, so i know it's correct
- No filters on 'environments' in Sentry.
- Nlog log file shows no errors. In fact in shows Sentry being wired up.
- Added other targets to NLog (e.g console, file, etc), they work fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe create an issue for the Sentry-project: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet

Comment: @rolf  What a strange target? It logs all to the internal log? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/src/Sentry.NLog/NLogDiagnosticLogger.cs

Comment: @Julian NLogDiagnosticLogger allows redirection of Sentry-Engine-Debug-Diagnostic-output to the NLog-InternalLogger.

Comment: @RPM1984 Did you remember to flush? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush

Comment: @RolfKristensen the app is running for a while, and other messages are being logged to other sinks, therefore NLog is 'flushed'. will create an issue on Sentry GH.

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/817

Comment: @RolfKristensen you were right. issue was i wasn't waiting long enough to 'flush'. I didn't need to explicitly call flush, i just needed to wait longer :( feel free to chuck up an answer and ill mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentry is sending data over the network, and propbably has an artificial delay to optimize for batching and to reduce network-traffic.

[Did you remember to flush?](http://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush), and wait for the data to arrive at destination.

Answer (score 1):

Did you opt out of `InitializeSdk`?

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/6ce7f933f64bd517677b5e837d6c7e8cc37b4217/src/Sentry.NLog/SentryTarget.cs#L148-L155

Could that be the issue?

Unless you're using another integration which already initialized Sentry, of if you call `SentrySdk.Init` yourself though.

But by default the DSN alone should be enough to init the SDK.
[You can set the SDK to debug mode to see what's happening](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/nlog/configuration/options/#debug).

There's a sample project in the repo:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/tree/main/samples/Sentry.Samples.NLog

Comment: Answered on the GH issue. :) Should I close this SO question?